# finding the lowest value in a cell Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to this. I am trying to find the lowest value in a cell with multiple values inside. For example,

48
44.50
41.00
37.50

I am trying to find 37.50. What should be the code for it?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple values within a cell?  Do you mean within a range?

Comment: sorry if I am not being clear, new to excel, it's like one cell that has multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted example:

```
Sub FindMin()
   Dim s As String, CH As String
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Dim bry() As Double
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   s = ActiveCell.Text

   CH = Chr(10)
   ary = Split(s, CH)
   ReDim bry(LBound(ary) To UBound(ary))

   For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
      bry(i) = CDbl(ary(i))
   Next i

   MsgBox wf.Min(bry)
End Sub
```

[image]

This assumes that there is a hard return (*ASCII-10*) between the fields in the cell.

**EDIT#1:**

To make it into a function, **remove** the sub and **replace** with:

```
Public Function FindMin(r As Range) As Variant
   Dim s As String, CH As String
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Dim bry() As Double
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   s = r.Text

   CH = Chr(10)
   ary = Split(s, CH)
   ReDim bry(LBound(ary) To UBound(ary))

   For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
      bry(i) = CDbl(ary(i))
   Next i

   FindMin = wf.Min(bry)
End Function
```

**EDIT#2:**

based on your comment, here is an example of input *vs* output:

[image]

Note that all the values are in a single cell and the values are separated by hard returns rather than spaces.

Comment: how would you make it return into a cell instead of a pop up?

Comment: I got a error in value when I used this. Why is that?

Comment: @user3496026  I would need to see your input cell.

Comment: is the input cell the one with all the values? if so the values I have are:
22.00 
2.00
2.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
5.00
6.00
3.00
3.00
3.00
4.00
4.00
5.00
6.00
7.00
8.00
10.00
12.00
16.00
21.00
2.00

Comment: would there be a difference in code if its separated by hard return than spaces?

Comment: @user3496026  If there was a **space** rather than a **hard-return** between the values, change `CH = Chr(10)` to `CH = Chr(32)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79679/discussion-between-user3496026-and-garys-student).

Answer (score 0):

By code with same cell and a " " as delimiter to break

```
temp = Range("A1").Value

temp = Split(temp, " ")

Low = CInt(temp(0))

For i = 0 To UBound(temp) - 1
    If CInt(temp(i)) < Low Then Low = CInt(temp(i))
Next

Range("a2").Value = Low
```

if they are in a range you can use a formula

```
=MIN(A1:A4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty close to one previously asked:
[VBA/EXCEL: extract numbers from one cell that contained multiple values with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047849/vba-excel-extract-numbers-from-one-cell-that-contained-multiple-values-with-com)

If you take the code from that answer and replace the comma with whatever is separating your values, you will be able to get access to them in VBA.  Then you can write code to find the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a macro to split the values for each cell you selected and then check for the highest value. And a quick check to make sure you are not parsing all the empty rows (when you selected a column).

The macro below will set the highest value in the next column.

```
Sub lowest()

    Dim Values As Variant
    Dim LowestValue As Double

    Dim a As Range

    Set a = Selection

    For Each Row In a.Rows

      For Each Cell In Row.Cells

        LowestValue = -1
        Values = Split(Cell.Value, Chr(10))

        For Each Value In Values

            If LowestValue = -1 Then
                LowestValue = Value
            ElseIf Value < LowestValue Then
                LowestValue = Value
            End If
        Next

        Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column + 1).Value = LowestValue
        If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then GoTo EndLoop

      Next Cell

    Next Row

EndLoop:

End Sub
```